# Is it possible to name polygons in ArcMap attribute table using my native language?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

now I am using ArcMap 10 to modify a land use map and i also would like to use my own native language to name those edited polygons instead of using English one because some users cannot read English. If anyone knows how to do that please help.

Comment: How is your data stored: shapefile or a geodatabase (file, personal, or enterprise)?  Does your native language use non-latin characters?

Answer (score 1):

Well, What kind of data do you have?

I assume you have shapefile...in that case Start Editing and you would be able to edit names and change it in your native language. but if it is just a map you scanned it and then digitized it in that case, I am afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shapefile, just add a field and name it as your own native language and don't delete the English field because you might need it later in case if you spell it wrong or something like that.